# Django media files

Tags: python, django

My Setting.py file contains

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/media/'
```

When I load a page, I get

```
GET /media/covers/lo.png HTTP/1.1" 404
```

When I change MEDIA_URL to '/static/media/' and copy my media folder to that path it works!

What's wrong?

Comment: What are your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` settings?

Comment: Check above, I edited the post.

Comment: I guess you have saved your medias directory under the `STATIC_ROOT` so it is served under `/static/`

Comment: Just to check: are you running this in debug mode / with the django built-in server?  I'm speculating you need to do the from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
) bit

Comment: I have tried running with both debug set to false and true, same result. Yes I am using the Django built-in server